# Microsoft Flow - create Blob Storage when a ftp file is added or modified

Tags: ftp, azure-blob-storage, power-automate

I'm using Microsoft Flow to store files from an FTP. I've three flows for different folders from the FTP which store each in the different containers.

For example:

```
ftp/folder A a blob/container A
ftp/folder B a blob/container B
ftp/folder C a blob/container C
```

Each folder from the ftp updates diary and uploads 3 files: summary (`*.txt`) , lookup data (`*.tar.gz`) and data file (`*.tsv.gz`).

But just one flow works as it has to, it means, upload the three files on the container. The others just upload only two files: summary and lookup data but not the data file. I don't know why the flow doesn't upload the data files.

Just to give you more information,

the size of the files are:

1. Folder A (flow don't work)

- summary: 358 B
- lookup data: 3.58 MB
- data file: 2181 MB

2. Folder B (flow don't work)

- summary: 341 B
- lookup data: 3.59 MB
- data file: 1135MB

3. Folder C (flow work)

- summary: 339 B
- lookup data: 3.55 MB
- data file: 15.58 MB

Flow Design:

[image: flow design]

Folder A:

```
FTP- When a file is added or modified
ENTRADAS
Carpeta
/Folder A
Include file content
True
SALIDAS
Contenido del archivo
Datafeed-Manifest-Version: 1.0
Lookup-Files: 1
Data-Files: 1
Total-Records: 1374468
Lookup-File: folderA-fecha.tar.gz
MD5-Digest: ****
File-Size: 3775354
Data-File: folderA-fecha.tsv.gz
MD5-Digest: *****
File-Size: 152845674
Record-Count: 1374468
Nombre de archivo
folderA-fecha.txt
Ruta del archivo
/folderA-fecha/folderA-fecha.txt
Etiqueta de entidad de archivo
+++++
Tipo de contenido del archivo
text/plain

Blob Storage - Create Blob
ENTRADAS
Ruta de acceso de la carpeta
/folder A
Nombre del blob
folderA-fecha.txt
Contenido del blob
Datafeed-Manifest-Version: 1.0
Lookup-Files: 1
Data-Files: 1
Total-Records: 1374468
Lookup-File: folderA-fecha.tar.gz
MD5-Digest: ******
File-Size: 3775354
Data-File: folderA-fecha.tsv.gz
MD5-Digest: ******
File-Size: 152845674
Record-Count: 1374468
SALIDAS
Id
+++
Name
folderA-fecha.txt
DisplayName
folderA-fecha.txt
Path
/folderA/folderA-fecha.txt
LastModified
2017-02-10T07:01:56Z
Size
358
MediaType
text/plain
IsFolder
false
ETag
+++++
FileLocator
+++++
```

Folder B:

```
FTP- When a file is added or modified
ENTRADAS
Carpeta
/folderB
Include file content
True
SALIDAS
Contenido del archivo
Datafeed-Manifest-Version: 1.0
Lookup-Files: 1
Data-Files: 1
Total-Records: 614946
Lookup-File: folderB-fecha.tar.gz
MD5-Digest: ****
File-Size: 3774897
Data-File: folderB-fecha.tsv.gz
MD5-Digest: *****
File-Size: 88794131
Record-Count: 614946
Identificador de archivo
+++++
Nombre de archivo
folderB.txt
Ruta del archivo
/folderB/folderB-fecha.txt
Etiqueta de entidad de archivo
+++++
Tipo de contenido del archivo
text/plain

Blob Storage - Create Blob
ENTRADAS
Ruta de acceso de la carpeta
/folderB
Nombre del blob
folderB-fecha.txt
Contenido del blob
Datafeed-Manifest-Version: 1.0
Lookup-Files: 1
Data-Files: 1
Total-Records: 614946
Lookup-File: folderB-fecha.tar.gz
MD5-Digest: ******
File-Size: 3774897
Data-File: folderB-fecha.tsv.gz
MD5-Digest: *****
File-Size: 88794131
Record-Count: 614946
SALIDAS
Id
+++++
Name
folderB-fecha.txt
DisplayName
folderB-fecha.txt
Path
/folderB/folderB-fecha.txt
LastModified
2017-02-10T06:46:51Z
Size
341
MediaType
text/plain
IsFolder
false
ETag
+++++
FileLocator
+++++
```

Folder C:

```
FTP- When a file is added or modified
SALIDAS
Contenido del archivo
Datafeed-Manifest-Version: 1.0
Lookup-Files: 1
Data-Files: 1
Total-Records: 71323
Lookup-File: folderC-fecha.tar.gz
MD5-Digest: *******
File-Size: 3774936
Data-File: folderC-fecha.tsv.gz
MD5-Digest: *******
File-Size: 14724852
Record-Count: 71323
Nombre de archivo
folderC-fecha.txt
Ruta del archivo
/folder C/folderC-fecha.txt
Etiqueta de entidad de archivo
+++++
Tipo de contenido del archivo
text/plain

Blob Storage - Create Blob
 
ENTRADAS
Ruta de acceso de la carpeta
/folderC
Nombre del blob
folderC-fecha.txt
Contenido del blob
Datafeed-Manifest-Version: 1.0
Lookup-Files: 1
Data-Files: 1
Total-Records: 71323
Lookup-File: folderC-fecha.tar.gz
MD5-Digest: *****
File-Size: 3774936
Data-File: folcerC-fecha.tsv.gz
MD5-Digest: ****
File-Size: 14724852
Record-Count: 71323
SALIDAS
Id
++++++
Name
folderC-fecha.txt
DisplayName
folderC-fecha.txt
Path
/folderC/folderC-fecha.txt
LastModified
2017-02-10T06:20:05Z
Size
339
MediaType
text/plain
IsFolder
false
ETag
++++++
FileLocator
++++++
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum size of a file should be 50MB.